# GVim defaults in command line Vim

Tags: vim

Where are all the default plugins and color schemes form gvim located. I would like to create some sym links so that I can use them all in my command line vim.

I did a little searching before posting and saw this

> Yes, it is possible to make gvim exactly match terminal Vim. (It's not
>   always possible to go the other way, though, gvim allows more colors
>   so you can't always make terminal vim match if you're using gvim as
>   your base.)

EDIT: I'm on a Linux machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are supposed to be in the same place for GVim and Vim.

On UNIX-based systems you should put all your plugins and colorschemes in `~/.vim`.

If a plugin is installed there it's available in Vim and Gvim as long as both version numbers match the plugin's requirements.

I agree with your quote: "everything" that works in Vim will work in GVim but not the other way around. Mappings, for example, can make use of more keys in GVim than in Vim. Modal windows are possible in GVim but not in Vim. Like idigas wrote, the coolest GVim themes won't work in Vim because GVim supports thousands of colours while the best terminal emulators are limited to 256.

Because I use both GVim and Vim, I always think CLI Vim first to be safe.

Comment: Thanks for the info, For the past while I have used symlinks to keep additional plugins linked. However, here I am wondering about the default plugins that ship with GVim and how I can have access to them in CLI Vim.

Comment: What are those default plugins? Those in `/usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin`? As long as they don't depend 100% on the GUI they are all available to CLI Vim without needing any action from your part.

Comment: @romaini Yeah, I guess you're right. I'm looking through /usr/share/vim/vim72 now. Aside from being able to set color schemes there me no difference out of the box. I was thinking it had some other scripts built in. Maybe some key mappings are different too.

Comment: No. GVim is Vim wrapped in a custom GUI. GVim doesn't have anything that Vim doesn't have beside a custom GUI with menus, tooltips and modal dialogs. It doesn't even make use of your desktop environment's default shortcuts. That said, it may happen that some plugins only really make sense in GVim. They are not default, though.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your OS, vim (and gvim ...) sources the files from several locations, in this order (on Windows)

```
$HOME/vimfiles
$VIM/vimfiles
$VIMRUNTIME
$VIM/vimfiles/after ... and so on
```

You can see the contents of each `$HOME`, `$VIM` ... variable, with `echo $HOME`, `echo $VIM`. To see the list of those locations, depending on the OS, see `help vimfiles`.

Note: GVim and Vim (in a terminal) use different highlighting options. GVim uses `guibg/guifg`... Vim, `term` ...

Comment: Thanks Idigas. I should have mentioned I'm on a Linux machine. Also I should have mentioned that I'm looking to have access to the default plugins that ship with GVim. I have been able to access the contrib plugins in GVim and CLI Vim by using symlinks.